# Multiple plots in a page with R

Tags: r, plot

I have a problem. I want to arrange 7 plots in a single page: 3 plots in a top line, 2 plots below and 2 other below. I could'nt make it work with layout(matrix=)) (I think because the top line has an odd number of plots). I have used aplot and image.plot to make the plots. Thanks. Henri

Answer (score 2):

`layout` can *absolutely* do an odd number of plots on the top. You just need to think of more than 1 image per matrix element. Since you want 3 across the top and 2 across the other rows, then the lowest common multiple is 6. Make a layout with 6 columns.

```r
m <- matrix(c(1,1,2,2,3,3,
              4,4,4,5,5,5,
              6,6,6,7,7,7), ncol = 6, byrow = TRUE)
layout(m)
layout.show(7)
```

[image: layout grid]

FYI, this works equally well for rows as columns. The only strict "requirements" using `layout` are that all elements must be non-`NA`, non-negative, contiguous numbers (no numbers can be skipped). "0" means to skip a cell (a "hole" in the plot). Negatives are ignored, `NA`s are errors. It does not return an error if a set of plot numbers is not rectangular, but I won't guarantee that it'll always look like you want.

Comment: Thanks for this. Just after the post, I did what your are describing, it is working with plots done using " aplot", but image.plot completly mess all up and I did not understand why. I found a work around, I create 2 PDF files and then joined them in a single page with pdftools library. It is very elegant, but it works. Again thanks for the help. Henri

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `ggplot`, you might also consider using the `patchwork` package for this to make it easy. For example:

Step 1: Create all your figures and assign them to objects (e.g., `fig1`, `fig2` etc.). For example:

```r
fig1 <- ggplot(data = myData, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y) +
    geom_point()

#...etc.
```

Step 2: To create the layout to specified:

```r
library(patchwork)
(fig1 + fig2 + fig3) / (fig4 + fig5) / (fig6 + fig7)
```

Comment: I think `patchwork` will be necessary, since I think `aplot` is a ggplot2-using function (but `image.plot` is base graphics). In that case, it may be informative to know that `patchwork` can include base graphics (https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/articles/guides/assembly.html) by adding in `~ plot(...)` (suggesting that the base graphics must be created with a single function call).

Comment: Thanks. I found a work around. I create 2 PDf files and then put together in a same page with pdftools. Not sophisticated but it works. Thanks agsin. Henri